# WPF DataTemplateSelector is not used

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplateselector

I am trying to modify a existing WPF application in a way so that a newer version of some data object can be used alongside the old one. And so i avoid redundant code by extending the existing ViewModel with new fields where the old ones cannot be reused.

```
 public IList<G1VU.PDR> VuG1 { get; set; }
 public IList<G2VU.PDR> VuG2 { get; set; }
 public PlacesCompound VuP
 {
     get
     {
         if (VuG1 != null && VuG2 == null)
         {
            return new PlacesCompound {
                 G1 = VuG1,
                 G2 = null
             };
         }
         if (VuG2 != null && VuG1 == null)
         {
            return new PlacesCompound {
                G1 = null,
                G2 = VuG2
             };
         }

         throw new Exception("G1 and G2 data present or no data present");
     }
 }
```

`VuG1` has existed before and i have added a new property `VuG2` for the new data. As you can see these are not the same class so i cannot interchange them. For that reason i've added a property that will return either of the two in a `PlacesCompound` class, which is just a class with two properties and nothing else.

In the corresponding usercontrol (lets call it **ActivitiesView**) we have a DataGrid which binds to the ViewModel and somewhere a TabItem that will display a custom UserControl `places` which binds to `VuG1` on the ViewModel. I have copied it and changed it so it will work with `VuG2` Data.
And i created a custom `DataTemplateSelector` which will decide what Template to use based on which variable of `PlacesCompound` isnt `null`.

In `VUActivitiesResources.xaml` i have then declared 2 DataTemplates one for each `places` UserControl and the DataTemplateSelector.

```
<activities:VUActivitiesViewDataTemplateSelector x:Key="PlacesTemplateSelector"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="VuG2Template">
    <places:VUPViewG2 DataContext="{Binding VuG2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</DataTemplate>
    
<DataTemplate x:Key="VuG1Template">
    <places:VUPViewG1 DataContext="{Binding VuG1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

`VUActivitiesResources.xaml` is being referenced in **ActivitiesView** as `UserControl.Resources`.

In the **ActivitiesView** i placed a ItemsControl into the TabItem replacing the custom `places` UserControl (ive also tried a ListBox instead of a ItemsControl, but neither works)

```
<TabItem IsEnabled="{Binding PlacesIsVisible}">
    ...
    <ItemsControl
         ItemsSource="{Binding VuP}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PlacesTemplateSelector}"></ItemsControl>
</TabItem>
```

My question: why `PlacesTemplateSelector` is never used and how do i make it being used? Because right now while debugging i can see that in ViewModel `VuP` returns a `PlacesCompound` object correctly but the Selector is never entered. I want one of the two DataTemplates to show up in the TabItem and right now none is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemsSource must be a collection (which your PlacesCompound is not), in your case this would be either VuG1 or VuG2. If the two item classes have no common base class, you can still use `IEnumerable`:

```
public IEnumerable VuP => (IEnumerable)VuG1 ?? VuG2;
```

Then, instead of writing a TemplateSelector, just let the WPF DataTemplating mechanism do its work:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace1:PDR}">
    <places:VUPViewG2 HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</DataTemplate>
    
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace2:PDR}">
    <places:VUPViewG1 HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VuP}" />
```